# Can we get a recurrence relation for this sum?

Tags: recurrence-relations, hypergeometric-function

Suppose

$S_k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \frac{\left(a\right)_i\left(b\right)_{k-i} x^i}
{\left(c\right)_i\left(d\right)_{k-i}}$,

where $(a)_i = a(a+1)\cdots (a+i-1)$.

Note that the above sum can also be written in terms of a hypergeometric function ${}_3F_2$.  Is it possible to obtain a recurrence relation of $S_k$, i.e., express $S_k$ in terms of $S_{k-1}$, $S_{k-2}$, etc.

I want to get a recurrence relation because I want to save some calculations.  For example, if $k=100$, I need to sum up 101 terms to get $S_k$ but if a short recurrence relation can be obtained, say in terms of $S_{k-1}$, $S_{k-2}$ and $S_{k-3}$, then I can do this by summing up three terms.  Without the terms $(b)_{k-i}$ and $(d)_{k-i}$ in $S_k$, I can easily obtain a linear recurrence relation that expresses $S_k$ in terms of $S_{k-1}$ and $S_{k-2}$, but I could not get one for the $S_k$ above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Note that the above sum can also be written in terms of a hypergeometric function 3F2."  Specifically, it is exactly what you get when you take one parameter and set it equal to $-k$ and set $z := -x$ -- or, in other words, nearly the fully general thing.